# D3 graph seems to extend beyond x-axis (clipping issue with brush effect)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

My D3.js code is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/xyt4pbpo/11/

and Im trying to inject the graph into this haml view container within a rails app:

```
%section.content
.row
    .col-xs-12
      .panel.panel-primary
        .panel-heading
          %h3.panel-title
            %i.fa.fa-bar-chart-o
            Charging Sessions
        .panel-body
      #charging-sessions-chart
```

I know the issue starts on line 119 where I changed the d3.select to #charging-sessions-chart, but the problem is I need it embedded within that ID:

```
var svg = d3.select("#charging-sessions-chart").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
```

My question is how would I resolve this clipping issue?

EDIT: heres a photo of whats going on:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cWQZ.jpg

EDIT2: The graph looks fine until I utilize the brushing feature

EDIT3: The graph works perfectly fine outside of the rails environment. Must be something with the rails app.

Comment: Just created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/E8L6ipfTH58YwMvCrTrz?p=preview), it seems alright to me. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @HuguesStefanski the graph is fine until you utilize the brush feature

See the attached image above for a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/E8L6ipfTH58YwMvCrTrz?p=preview). I modified line 310 to add the `clip-path` as an [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) on the lines, as it is not a css style.

On a side note, I would personally create a group to contain all the lines and set the clip path on it, but the design is yours :-).

Comment: thank you! I am new to the site so I cant upvote but this solution worked. Much appreciation for sticking with the issue.